# Cannot add foreign key constraint using Laravel 5 migration

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a migration for an `orders` table. This table has a foreign key constraint for two tables: `employees`and `clients`.

The schema for the orders table:

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');

    $table->integer('client_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('client_id')->references('id')->on('clients');

    $table->integer('employee_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('employee_id')->references('id')->on('employees');

    $table->text('description');
    $table->string('status');
    $table->date('submitted_on');
    $table->date('completed_on');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The schema for the employees table:

```
Schema::create('employees', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('type');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

The schema for the clients table:

```
Schema::create('clients', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->increments('id');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')
            ->references('id')
            ->on('users')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

When I run the migration, the constraint is created successfully for the clients table, but for some reason it gives an error when attempting to create the constraint for employees:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>     SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint (SQL: alter table `orders` add constraint orders_employee_id_foreign foreign key (`employee_id`) references `employees` (`id`))

I pulled the query it was trying to use out and tried it directly on the database and got the same error:

```
-- Query:
alter table `orders` add constraint orders_employee_id_foreign foreign key (`employee_id`) references `employees` (`id`)
```

[image: MySQL error]

I'm a bit confused as far as what went wrong. The constraint setup is the same as the `clients` constraint and that is created successfully:

[image: Table info from Sequel Pro]

The syntax I'm using to create each of the constraints match. Is there a reason why it would create one but not the other?

### An aside

@PabloDigiani's solution of checking the creation order of the migrations was correct; the `orders` table was being created before the `employees` table which caused the error.

The solution was to make sure the `employees` migration ran *before* the `orders.

The aside I want to add is **how** to reorder the migrations in laravel. It's stated [here in the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/migrations#generating-migrations):

> Each migration file name contains a timestamp which allows Laravel to determine the order of the migrations.

When I checked the timestamp order, `employees` came after `orders` (just the arbitrary order in which I created the migrations via artisan):

[image: The errant order of migrations]

The fix was very simple: rename the migration for `employees` so that it's timestamp is before `orders`:

[image: Correct migration order]

Simple fix. Thanks again!

Comment: Does employees migration run before orders migration, right?

Comment: Try the `show create table employees` command and make sure the `id` on that table is the same collation utf8_unicode_ci and int(10).

Comment: @PabloDigiani good question. I checked and the `employee` table was being created after the `orders` table which was causing the constraint to fail (actually, the `employees` table wasn't even being created because of the error) . I changed the order in which the migrations fire so that `orders` is created after `employees` and it worked. If you want to add the answer below I'll give you the check. Thanks!!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When migrating a database with Laravel, it is important to check the order in which the tables are created.
In this case, employees table should be created before orders table. Otherwise, a foreign key constraint error will be thrown.

Just change the order of the table creation and your migration will run without errors.

Comment: when you change filename of migration dont forget to run `composer dump-autoload` will update file lists